# computing the difference between two consecutive rows for a set of condions

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to set a field equal to the difference of another field in the same row - another field in a previous row. What would be the best approach to do this? I have set a unique identification key for each row. What I am trying to do is:

```
If Member_ID (i+1)th row = Member_ID (i)th row and if Date (i+1)th row > Date (i)th row
    set Time_Between_Segment = DateDiff("n",[Date_Time_Out (i)],[Date_Time_In (i+1)].
```

Comment: sounds like grouping and using min and max to get the lower and upper records which will then be used to find the difference.

Comment: could you give some more information on using min and max. where would these functions be used?